# Qt Align QCheckBox to the top of the text

Tags: qt, alignment, qcheckbox

I looking for a way to align the QCheckBox box on the top of the text. The text is very long and I would like it to be aligned with the first line. I think by default it is vertically centered with the text. This seems pretty easy, but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the stylesheet :

```
QCheckBox::indicator {
    subcontrol-position: left top;
}
```

But the text is not aligned top by default so you need to align it too.